# Modify Fill Colour from Outside a Paint Event Handler in C# and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, random, colors, graphic

**What I Would Like to Do**
*Create and fill a rectangle, initially with a grey colour, then randomize that rectangle's fill colour with the press of a button.*
**What I Cannot Seem to Do**
*Modify properties of the aforementioned rectangle after it is initially drawn.*

**Random Colour Generator**

```
public static readonly Random random = new Random();
public static readonly object syncLock = new object();
public static int RandomNumber( int min, int max )
{
  lock(syncLock) {
    return random.Next(min, max);
  }
}
public Color randColourPicker() {
  Color randColour = Color.FromArgb(RandomNumber(0, 255), RandomNumber(0, 255), RandomNumber(0, 255));
  return randColour;
}
```

**Some** `randColourPicker()` **Calls**

```
public void randomizeColours() {
    this.BackColor = randColourPicker();
    clrRandLabel.ForeColor = randColourPicker();
    randomizeButton.BackColor = randColourPicker();
    randomizeButton.ForeColor = randColourPicker();
    loopCheckbox.ForeColor = randColourPicker();
}
```

**Rectangle Painting**

```
private void clrRandForm_Paint( object sender, PaintEventArgs e ) {
    int x = 266;
    int y = 105;
    int width = 274;
    int height = 172;

    Rectangle clrRect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    SolidBrush greyBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(75, 75, 75));
    SolidBrush randBrush = new SolidBrush(randColourPicker());
    Graphics clrGraphic = mainBox.CreateGraphics();

    clrGraphic.FillEllipse(greyBrush, clrRect);

    greyBrush.Dispose();
    randBrush.Dispose();
    clrGraphic.Dispose();
}
```

**More Info**
I have a button, and it's click event is bound to execute the `randomizeColours()` call, which in turn, swaps around the colours of various elements of the UI. I also have a check box that, when checked, runs through `randomizeColours()` on loop with a timer. I would like to do something similar, but with the fill colour of `clrRect`, but I cannot seem to figure out how I would access `clrGraphic.FillRectangle(greyBrush, clrRect)` outside of the PaintEvent function, so I can modify it to `clrGraphic.FillRectangle(randBrush, clrRect)`. `randBrush` is a brush I created with a random colour using `randColourPicker()`.

**Programs Used**
*Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012*

**P.S.**
*Sorry if this question is a duplicate, I couldn't quite figure out what to search for... Also, sorry if my code is cringe-worthy to some, I'm not really that good with the OOP approach or C-styled languages. :)*

Answer (score 0):

To change the Rectangle color you have to draw it again. You can keep your paint event function but with some changes. 
First, declare a global boolean First_time (initially set with true) that will check if you you want the greybrush or the Randbrush.

```
boolean First_Time;
```

Then in your Paint event :

```
private void clrRandForm_Paint( object sender, PaintEventArgs e ) {
    int x = 266;
    int y = 105;
    int width = 274;
    int height = 172;

    Rectangle clrRect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    SolidBrush greyBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(75, 75, 75));
    SolidBrush randBrush = new SolidBrush(randColourPicker());
    Graphics clrGraphic = mainBox.CreateGraphics();

    if(First_time)
        clrGraphic.FillEllipse(greyBrush, clrRect);
    else
        clrGraphic.FillEllipse(randBrush, clrRect);
    First_Time = false;

    greyBrush.Dispose();
    randBrush.Dispose();
    clrGraphic.Dispose();
}
```

And then in your button event, call:

```
this.Invalidate(); // or this.Refresh()
```

So that the Paint event is called again xD. 
I hope my advise was usefull.